# How to use methods in the constructor?

Tags: python-3.x

I'am making my first steps with Python. I have written very simple program, yet it is not working. The error messege is: `NameError: name 'fun' is not defined`.
 I'm using Spyder and Python 3.7.

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = fun()

    def fun(self):
        return 10

instance = myClass()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of self.a=fun() use self.a=self.fun() then only it will become clear to interpreter as to which fun() you are referring to.